# Compiling issue with hadoop pipes

Tags: hadoop

I have come across two approaches for compiling c++ programs using Hadoop pipes for Hadoop 1.2.0 and have had no luck with either of them.

Approach 1:

I came across the following link:

http://cs.smith.edu/dftwiki/index.php/Hadoop_Tutorial_2.2_--_Running_C%2B%2B_Programs_on_Hadoop

And made the following Makefile

```
CC = g++
HADOOP_INSTALL = /home/hduser/hadoop
PLATFORM = Linux-amd64-64
CPPFLAGS = -m64 -I$(HADOOP_INSTALL)/c++/$(PLATFORM)/include
wordcount: wordcount.cpp
        $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $< -Wall -L$(HADOOP_INSTALL)/c++/$(PLATFORM)/lib -lhadooppipes -lhadooputils -lpthread -g -O2 -o $@
```

Then I get a whole ton of undefined references

```
/home/hduser/hadoop/c++/Linux-amd64-64/lib/libhadooppipes.a(HadoopPipes.o): In function `HadoopPipes::BinaryProtocol::createDigest(std::string&, std::string&)':
HadoopPipes.cc:(.text._ZN11HadoopPipes14BinaryProtocol12createDigestERSsS1_[_ZN11HadoopPipes14BinaryProtocol12createDigestERSsS1_]+0x31): undefined reference to `EVP_sha1'
HadoopPipes.cc:(.text._ZN11HadoopPipes14BinaryProtocol12createDigestERSsS1_[_ZN11HadoopPipes14BinaryProtocol12createDigestERSsS1_]+0x6d): undefined reference to `HMAC_Init'
HadoopPipes.cc:(.text._ZN11HadoopPipes14BinaryProtocol12createDigestERSsS1_[_ZN11HadoopPipes14BinaryProtocol12createDigestERSsS1_]+0xa6): undefined reference to `HMAC_Update'
```

Approach 2:

I came across this tutorial

http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/C%2B%2BWordCount

I ran the following command

```
ant -Dcompile.c++=yes examples
```

And get the following error

```
Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
Build failed
```

I have no idea where I can get this build.xml file.  I found one in the installation folder in hadoop, but I don't think that is the correct one.

If anyone has had any luck with either one of these approaches, your comments would be truly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I can only help with your second approach:

The build file you're supposed to execute is the build.xml in the root of your hadoop distribution, alongside the LICENSE and README text files. Navigate to your hadoop-x.y.z directory and enter the command as stated.

This will only work if you downloaded the source distribution as opposed to the binary distribution, which does not contain the example source code. The c++ example source code is located in src/examples/pipes/impl

Answer (score 0):

I used to have the same issue. One solution is to link the crypto library.
For example, you can add `-lcrypto` to the compile command.

HTH
Shumin